# get index from multiple list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have this list in my program

```
private static List<User> us = new List<User>();
public string fNames, lNames, pWs, uNames;
public int uIds;
```

this is how I add the data to the list

```
 us.Add(new User { uIds = uId, fNames = fName, lNames = lName, pWs = password, uNames = uName+uId });
```

i need to get index of **us.uNames** in **us** list when input is same with **uName**

```
 Console.Write("Username : ");
 string uName = Console.ReadLine();

 int j = us[uNames].IndexOf(uName);
```

Comment: A) indexing a collection `[...]` takes an integer, you're giving it `uNames`, which is a string. B) After indexing `us`, you would receive a `User` object, which most likely doesn't have a `.IndexOf()` method.

Comment: Where do you ever populate the list `us`?

Comment: Very confusing what you trying to do (ideally you'd show example data and expected result). I think you are looking to find index of object in a list by property - and picked duplicate based on my understanding. If that is not the case please [edit] the question to clarify why FindIndex is not what you are looking for and show data along with desired  output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this? I mean find the index of item where `uNames` is equal to the given value?

```
var index = us.FindIndex(c => c.uNames == uName);
```